# $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian where $G$ is a group and $Z(G)$ is the center of the group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I read the proof of this theorem but the question i have is If $G/Z(G)$ IS Cyclic then $G$ is abelian therefore $G = Z(G)$ which implies that $G/Z(G) = \{e\}$. Am i right?
For example If $o(G/Z(G)) =11$ then $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic therefore $G$ is abelian which implies that $o(G/Z(G)) = 1$ a contradiction. Please explain or correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: $G/Z(G)$, if non-trivial, cannot be cyclic. (Although we usually do not regard the trivial group as cyclic.)

Comment: @HongyiHuang Why is the trivial group not cyclic, see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Trivial_Group_is_Cyclic_Group)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, but I just neglect it. Thank you!

Comment: The question is if G/Z(G) is cyclic then can it only be trivial?

Comment: Yes; I don’t like that phrasing of the problem precisely because it leads to the sort of “wait-a-minute” moment you’re having. A better phrasing for the problem is the following: *“Let $G$ be a group. Prove that if $G/N$ is cyclic with $N\leq Z(G)$, then $G$ is abelian.”*

Comment: @HongyiHuang: “Although we usually do not regard the trivial group as cyclic”... ehr, yes, we do.